# Is there a way to test paypal IPN protocol with an additional parameter?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I added an additional parameter in the paypal button code.
This value represents the user_id inside my wordpress website.

Is there a way to simulate the IPN protocol passing this parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can't create your own parameters.  You'll need to use the INVOICE parameter and pass a record ID of some sort, or you can use the CUSTOM parameter to include value you need to pull back out of IPN.

There is an IPN Simulator built in to the tools at developer.paypal.com, but it's not perfect.  What I like to do is build an HTML form with the action set to my IPN URL and then a bunch of hidden fields that resemble what I would expect to get back from a PayPal IPN.  This can be loaded in a browser and submitted so you can see the result on screen which can really help with testing and troubleshooting.  Once everything works the way you expect within the browser you can be sure it'll work the same with a real IPN.

Just keep in mind that when testing that way the data is not coming from PayPal's server so it will not be VERIFIED.  You'll need to make sure your IPN code logic can handle that accordingly.